# Add script tag to index.html during runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the following document and I want to add to it script under the title after the page load,how should I do that ?

This is my simple page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simple demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Demo</h1>
<p>
Very simple UI – just text and a link:
<a id="demoLink" href="#">Click me!</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The script should be very simple

```
<script>console.log(test) </script>
```

is it possible at all ? if not how should I do that via console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to load a script after page load you'd need to add it in like this:

```
<script>
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://something.com/js/something.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks I try to put the code that you provide in the chrome console and I put in the script.src = console.log("text") but when I take a look at the index page nothing was changed any idea why?btw when I do document.getEle...how should I refer to the index.html ?

Comment: the script src is to link to an external javascript file, you cant put inline javascript in it

Answer (score 0):

After the page load, there's no major difference between "adding an script node" or "executing a piece of script". If you do want to add the `<script>`node in `<head>`, you could use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).